# Cos'è "la vedetta" in "Bastardi senza gloria" di Quentin Tarantino?

Tags: word-meaning

In "Bastardi senza gloria" di Quentin Tarantino, vi è una scena in cui il tenente Aldo Raine (Brad Pitt) ed i suoi commando si travestono da operatori di una troupe cinematografica italiana ed incontrano il colonnello Hans Landa delle SS (Christoph Waltz). La scena è molto buffa in quanto l'italiano stentato dei militari americani è contrastato dall'inaspettato buon italiano del colonnello, il quale, dopo essere stato presentato, [dice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OxEY3DRJUFs)

> Signori, è un piacere! Gli amici della **vedetta**, ammirata da tutti noi, questa gemma proprio della nostra cultura saranno naturalmente accolti sotto la mia protezione per la durata del loro soggiorno.

Sapreste dirmi a che cosa si riferisce il colonnello Hans Landa quando parla de "la vedetta"? Ho pensato in principio ad un qualche riferimento al Fascismo, ma non ho trovato nulla a parte il nome di qualche [giornale](http://www.giovannispitale.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/la-provincia-di-vicenza-marcia-su-roma.pdf) dell'epoca.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ascoltando il sonoro del video da te menzionato mi pare che pronunci *vedetta* ma la parola corretta, perlomeno quella usata nel linguaggio comune, dovrebbe essere ***vedette***, riferendosi al personaggio interpretato da Diane Kruger  cioè l'attrice tedesca Bridget Von Hammersmark.

Infatti su Treccani per [vedette](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/vedette/):

> *vedette* ⟨*vëdèt*⟩ s. f., fr. [dall’ital. *vedetta*, e con gli stessi sign.
> della voce ital.; il sign. qui definito è dalla locuz. *mettre un nom
> en vedette*, e rispettivam. *ëtre en vedette*, su un cartellone, un
> manifesto, un programma, mettere o avere il nome bene in vista, in
> modo che, per la posizione e i caratteri più grossi, abbia risalto su
> tutti gli altri]. – Attrice (e più raram. attore) di grande successo e
> notorietà del teatro di varietà e della rivista, o del cinema e di
> trasmissioni televisive dello stesso tipo: *una v. del café chantant;
> le grandi vedettes della rivista italiana, dei film musicali
> americani; Maurice Chevalier fu una celebre v. internazionale.*

Come si vede deriva dall'italiano *vedetta* e magari essendo il film ambientato durante l'occupazione nazista in Francia, si è voluto usare il nome italianizzato, visto che in epoca fascista tutti i vocaboli stranieri erano sostituiti dalla variante italiana.

Comment: Personalmente mi sembra che dica proprio _vedette_, ma è difficile dirlo visto che la parola successiva comincia per “a”.

Comment: Durante i primi ascolti mi pare di percepire vedetta, ma sono d'accordo con te sul fatto che sia difficile discriminare in questo caso.

Comment: Interessante, non conoscevo proprio questa parola. Avevo trovato una trascrizione che usava _vedette_, ma l'ho tacciata di errore di battitura. Chissà che non dica anche "questa gemma _propria_ della nostra cultura".

Answer (score 5):

In realtà dice “Gli amici della *vedette* ammirata...”, dove [*vedette*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/vedette) è un termine un po' antiquato ma ancora in uso per indicare un'“Attrice ... di grande successo e notorietà del teatro di varietà e della rivista” (Treccani).